# Prove a generalization for a formula involving an inner-product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inner-products

Let $V$, a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ from a finite dimension with an inner product $\beta \langle .,. \rangle$. Let $B=\{v_1,\ldots, v_n\}$, a basis for $V$.
If $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ is an orthonormal basis, we have learn in class (apparently. I didn't) that:

For $v,w\in V$: $$ \beta(v,w) = \overline{([v]_B)^T} \cdot [w]_B $$

I need to prove the generalization (**for any basis, not necessarily an orthonormal**)  of this, for:

$$ \beta(v,w) = \overline{([v]_B)^T} \cdot G \cdot [w]_B $$

Where $G\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ such that $G_{ij} = \beta(v_i,v_j)$

Comment: Yes...and thus $\;G=I=$ the identity matrix, and the formula you need to prove is completely trivial. Perhaps it was intended to be proved for **any** other basis, not precisely an orthonormal one?

Comment: Oh, it should make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $\;v,w\in V\;$ and express them as linear combinations of the given orthonormal basis:

$$\begin{cases}v=\sum\limits_{k=1}^na_iv_i\\{}\\w=\sum\limits_{k=1}^nb_iv_i\end{cases}$$

so using the basic properties of a complex inner product:

$$\beta(v,w)=\beta\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^na_iv_i\,,\,\,\sum\limits_{k=1}^nb_iv_i\right)=\sum_{i,j=1}^na_i\overline {b_j}\,\overbrace{\beta(v_i,v_j)}^{\delta_{ij}}=\sum_{i=1}^na_i\overline{b_i}=\left([v]_B\right)^t\overline{[w]_B}$$

where $\;[v]_B\;$ means *column vector* .

The above is what you say you apparently didn't learn, but now you have.

Now, if $\;B=\{v_1,...,v_n\}\;$ is *not* precisely an orthonormal basis, can you see how the matrix $\;G=(\beta(v_i,v_j))\;$ fits in the formula? Complete the argument.

Comment: I'll have to ponder on it a little. Thank you in the meantime.

Comment: Aren't you missing a bar in the RHS: $\sum_{i=1}^na_i\overline{b_i}=\left([v]_B\right)^t[w]_B$?

Comment: Yes I am, thank you...and BTW: the bar must be over $\;w\;$ , *not* over $\;v\;$ . Editing now.

Comment: I'm confused. How can you even define $\beta(w,v)$ if the terms in $G$ are $\beta(v_i,v_j)$?

Comment: @AlonAlon Just write each vector as a linear combination of the basis $\;\{v_u\}\;$ as I did: that's all! In case the basis is orthonormal it comes up very nicely, as shown before, but in the general case it is the same: in my middle line, after the second equality sign, you already have the very definition of $\;[v]_BG\overline{[w]_B}\;$ , as you can write $$a_i\overline{b_j}\beta(v_i,v_j)=a_i\beta(v_i,v_j)\overline{b_j}\;\;\;!$$ Please do note: I do **not** define $\;\beta\;$ in the terms of anything: the inner product $\;\beta\;$ is *given* a priori. I just use it.

Comment: Those $v_i, v_j$ are part of the original **orthonormal** basis?

Comment: No @AlonAlon, as then what new thing would we be doing?! It is just to use your notation: assume you have another basis (call it this time $\;\{u_1,...,u_n\}\;$ if you want, to avoid confusion), and the matrix $\;G=\left(\beta(u_i,u_j)\right)\;$ and then do as shown above: write each vector as a l.c. of this basis, use the properties of inner product and etc.

Comment: OK, I'll give it a shot..

Comment: Oh I see now. Thanks a lot! :)